# How would I make a simple recursive function outputting the number of divisors a number has?

Tags: python, recursion

In an online class, I received this problem.

Write a function numDivisors( N ) that returns the number of integers from 1 to N (inclusive) that divide N evenly. For example, numDivisors(42) would return 8, since 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, and 42 are divisors of 42. (Python 2.7)

Although I have solved it with a loop, I'm wondering how I would go about this with recursion.

The basic functionality of this function with a loop would be:

```
def numDivisors( N ):    
    """ returns # of integers that divide evenly into N """
    divisors = 1 # the factor 1
    if N != 1:
      divisors += 1 # the factor N

    for i in range(2,int(N)): # loops through possible divisors
      if N % i == 0: # factor found
        divisors += 1
    return divisors
```

How could I implement it recursively using the bare basics (declaration, conditionals, looping, etc. up to list comprehensions)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If we have to be recursive:

```
>>> def ndiv(N, i=1):
...    return 1 if N==i else ((N % i == 0) + ndiv(N, i+1))
...
```

Let's test it.  As per the question:

> For example, numDivisors(42) would return 8

```
>>> ndiv(42)
8
```

Thus, this produces the desired output.

If we can do away with recursion, here is how to do it just using list comprehension:

```
>>> def div(N):
...     return sum(1 for i in range(1, N+1) if N % i == 0)
... 
>>> div(42)
8
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
def find_divisors(N,i=1):
    if i >= N**0.5+1: return set([])
    if N%i == 0: return set([i,N//i]).union(find_divisors(N,i+1))
    return find_divisors(N,i+1)
```

recursion is a pretty lousy solution to this problem ... do you really need to find all the divisors? or are you looking for a special one?

Comment: This algorithm does not produce correct results, it misses the square root if `N` is a perfect square, e.g. `N=4` -> `set([1, 4])`, `N=9` -> `set([1, 9])` etc.